# Table too wide, first column too big?

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,  % Seitenformat
            12pt,                               
            bibliography=totoc,     
            index=totoc,    
            abstracton,     
            headsepline,    
            %footnosepline, 
            ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\toprule
Test& test &test&test tes t&test test &test test &tes tes t&test test \\
\midrule
test& -0,0000615 & 0,0145 &  0,02783&&\\
&(0.000895) &(0.000633) &&& \\
test& -0,0004447 & 0,0152  & 0,0294&&\\
 &(0.00094)&(0.000664) & &&\\
test&-0,000107 & 0,0234  &  0.04584&&\\
&(0.001445) &(0.00102)&&&\\
test& -0.00075 & 0,01285 &  0.0244&&\\
&(0.000792) &(0.00056)&&&\\
\bottomrule
\begin{footnotesize}std. errors in parentheses\end{footnotesize}
\end{tabular}
\caption{VaR$_{0,975}$ values using formula \ref{variancenormal}}
\label{vartvalues}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following picture

[image]

1. The first column is clearly too big, why? How can I change this?
2. How can I make the table to fit in? So it is too wide now, it is in the right margin, what I don't want, so how can I make the table fit?

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize std. ...}`

Answer (score 2):

You want that the last row spans all the columns, so

```
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}
```

will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but the table is still too big, so it is still in the right margin? @egreg

Comment: ok, I found a solution: \hspace*{-1cm}, but this needs manual adjustment, isn't there something like \centerline for tables?

Comment: @StatTistician Put the entire table in `\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`. But I'd try fixing it before resorting to these tricks. Can you add a small sample of the real table?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to encasing the string `std. errors in parentheses` in a `\multicolumn{8}{l}{...}` directive -- as already suggested by @egreg -- I'd recommend you load the `siunitx` package to pretty-print the numerical columns. The following example might work for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format = 2.7,
         group-digits = false,
         input-symbols = {()-+},
         input-open-uncertainty  = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         input-decimal-markers = {,.},
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{l *{7}{S} }
\toprule
Test& {test} &{test} &{test}&{test}&{test}&{test}&{test}\\
\midrule
test& -0,0000615 & 0,0145 &  0,02783&&\\
&(0.000895) &(0.000633) &&& \\
test& -0,0004447 & 0,0152  & 0,0294&&\\
 &(0.00094)&(0.000664) & &&\\
test&-0,000107 & 0,0234  &  0.04584&&\\
&(0.001445) &(0.00102)&&&\\
test& -0.00075 & 0,01285 &  0.0244&&\\
&(0.000792) &(0.00056)&&&\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize std.\ errors in parentheses}
\end{tabular}
\caption{VaR$_{0,975}$ values using formula \ref{variancenormal}}
\label{vartvalues}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```